# Bootstrap Change css depending on mobile layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to know how i can change the css of my web in bootstrap,depending on the screen size,because i want change the text sizes and images too,but i dont know how,thanks.
here its my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/onepage-scroll.css">



    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Summa</title>



   <!-- Fuentes -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sniglet' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet"> 


    <!-- Fuentes final -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover-min.css">









<body>



        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="imagenes/icono.png" 
        style="width: 25px; height: 25px; ">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 
      <div class="main">

      <header> 




  <section>
    <div class="homepage-hero-module">
       <div class="video-container">
        <div class="filter" ></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="videos/Noted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

        </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="imagenes/groot.gif" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

   <div class="col-md-12" id="logo">
<img class="center-block img-responsive" src="imagenes/logo.png" >

     <a ><span></span></a>
    </div>
</section>
   </header> 





    <section class="container-fluid fullscreen">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
      <h3 id="colorletra">Brindamos soluciones y conectamos empresas </h3>
      <h4 id="colorletra2">Te invitamos a conocer nuestras especialidades y demas servicios</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" id="colorletra3"><h2>Mantenimiento</h2></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4" id="colorletra3"><h2>Soporte</h2></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4" id="colorletra3"><h2>Venta</h2></div>

      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4 hvr-pulse-grow" ><img src="imagenes/settings.svg" class="img-responsive center-block" id="tamanoicono"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4 hvr-pulse-grow" ><a href="login.html"><img src="imagenes/message.svg" class="img-responsive center-block" id="tamanoicono"></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4 hvr-pulse-grow" ><img src="imagenes/credit-card.svg" class="img-responsive center-block" id="tamanoicono"></div>


      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" id="colorletra4"><h4>Ofrecemos diferentes planes de mantenimiento para sus productos</h4></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4" id="colorletra4"><h4>Verifique el estado de sus productos online y envie dudas o consultas.</h4></div>
      <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4" id="colorletra4"><h4>Adquiera en linea cualquiera de nuestros productos por medio de nuestra tienda interactiva</h4></div>





     </section>

     <section class="container-fluid talleres fullscreen">




       <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
     <h1 id="somos">Quienes somos?</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6"><h4 id="colorletra5">Ingeniería Integrada, nace en el año 2004 como una iniciativa de un grupo de profesionales del sector de las telecomunicaciones de crear empresa y dar mantenimiento predictivo, preventivo y correctivo, a equipos de telecomunicaciones y tarjetas; Con el tiempo fue ampliando sus servicios a equipos de Energía, Radio y Televisión hasta lograr en el año 2005 cubrimiento en estaciones de comunicaciones celulares.
Con la experiencia y equipos de última tecnología fuimos irrumpiendo en otros sectores de la economía nacional logrando abarcar otros mercados como el transporte masivo, la industria y la salud.
Hemos ido creciendo, logrando reconocimientos a nivel nacional como empresa ingenio en la ciudad de Medellín, dado que contamos con un laboratorio de Innovación y desarrollo que nos ha permitido diseñar equipos especializados, enfocados a la necesidad de cada cliente y distinciones como Gestora en la Participación de Proyectos.</h4>
  </div>




       </section>





       <section id="video1">

    <iframe
      id="JotFormIFrame-62446220115646"
      onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
      allowtransparency="true"
      src="https://form.jotformz.com/62446220115646"
      frameborder="0"
      style="width:100%;
      height:539px;
      border:none;"
      scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.handleIFrameMessage = function(e) {
        var args = e.data.split(":");
        var iframe = false;
        if (args.length > 2) { iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame-" + args[2]); } else { iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame"); }
        if (!iframe)
          return;
        switch (args[0]) {
          case "scrollIntoView":
            iframe.scrollIntoView();
            break;
          case "setHeight":
            iframe.style.height = args[1] + "px";
            break;
          case "collapseErrorPage":
            if (iframe.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
              iframe.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
            }
            break;
          case "reloadPage":
            window.location.reload();
            break;
        }
        var isJotForm = (e.origin.indexOf("jotform") > -1) ? true : false;
        if(isJotForm && "contentWindow" in iframe && "postMessage" in iframe.contentWindow) {
          var urls = {"docurl":encodeURIComponent(document.URL),"referrer":encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)};
          iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"type":"urls","value":urls}), "*");
        }
      };
      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", handleIFrameMessage, false);
      } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleIFrameMessage);
      }
      if(window.location.href && window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        var ifr = false;
        if (args.length > 2) { ifr = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame-" + args[2]); } else { ifr = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame"); }
        var get = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1);
        if(ifr && get.length > 0) {
          var src = ifr.src;
          src = src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? src + "&" + get : src  + "?" + get;
          ifr.src = src;
        }
      }
      </script>

  </section>








         </div>




<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>



  <script>$(".main").onepage_scroll(); </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#video1{
min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}


#logo{
  position: absolute;
height:70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;

  margin: auto;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;



}
#colorletra{
color:darkslategray;
    padding-top: 8%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}
#colorletra2{
color:darkslategray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#colorletra3{

    color:darkslategray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#colorletra4{

    color:darkslategray;
 text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;  
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#colorletra5{

    color:whitesmoke;
 text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: center;  
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#alcentro{
text-align: center;
}
.talleres{

  background-image: radial-gradient(at top left, #3A8FDC 0%, #87D7CD 100%);
  padding: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#descripciones{
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}
#tamanoicono{
width: 10em;
}
.quien{
    background-image: radial-gradient(at top left, #5C258D 0%, #4389A2 100%);
}
#proy{
font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: aliceblue;
}
#somos{
     color:whitesmoke;
 text-align: center;

  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
    padding-top: 25%;

}



a {

    padding-top: 60px;
}
a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    content: '';
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: sdb 2s infinite;
    animation: sdb 2s infinite;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 30px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes sdb {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translate(0, 40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
   .fullscreen { height: 100vh; }



.homepage-hero-module {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
    display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
    display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And i read about css in the bootstrap documentation but i dont find any information about that,help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries. Change width according to you device width. Put the class/Id/elements of the font container in the media curly braces.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS media queries to make your website's responsive for different screen sizes.

As in your code you can change your style to #logo as follow.

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    #logo {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

The above css rules applied for screens with maximum width of 600px.You can change that value as your wish. So font-size of #logo will be 15px when you view you website with 600px max width screen.

OR you can set your screen size to different CSS files when they are linking to HTML doc. To do that you need to specify your wishing screen size to the `<link>` tag with media attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 600px)" href="example.css" />
```

The CSS rules written inside that example.css file , will only applied to screens with max-width of 600px.

This W3School's tute may help you : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Best Regards 
!